# Infinite sum of cos(ln(n))/n

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series, exponential-sum

What would be the value of the infinite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\ln n}{n}$$

Comment: i'll be very glad to know why this question is seen as "off topic" by some people, since i don't want to violate the community rules (which i've read)

Comment: The point is: what is your effort?

Comment: i'm studying some kind of trigonometric sum and trying to attack it in many directions. very long and indeed offtopic to describe that. anyway still unclear to me how i violate the community rules

Comment: Perhaps edit your question and include what you have tried and what you want to try but are unable to.  It's more likely you'll get a response if you don't treat SE as a homework bot.

Comment: It is not convergent. It is $$\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ for $s=1-i$, but such series is convergent only if $\text{Re}(s)>1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks, interesting, i saw that cos(n)/n converges, it's a surprise for me to see that cos(ln(n))/n won't converge

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(n)}{n}$ is convergent, but that is not related. What I am exploiting here is $$\cos\log n=\text{Re}\exp(i\log n) = \text{Re}n^i.$$

Comment: yes i see, thanks for the on-topic answer for the "off-topic" question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $ \Re(s) > 0$
$$\Re(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\frac{1-(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1}) = \Re(\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx)$$
The RHS gives the series
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \Re(\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx) \le   \int_1^\infty |sx^{-s-1}|dx=\frac{|s|}{\Re(s)}$$ which converges absolutely and $$\lim_{N \to \infty}\Re(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\frac{1-(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1})$$ Converges.

Your series is obtained with $s=1+i$ so that  $\Re(\frac{1-(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1})$ is bounded but it oscillates without converging.

Comment: thanks, nice trick with converting a sum to integrals from n to n+1, i was unfamiliar with it